# Insert correct HDD

Tags: hard-disk

I want to insert a HDD into Dell Precision 3561.

The [specs](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/precision-15-3561-laptop_owners-manual2_en-us.pdf) says:

> One 2.5-inch hard drive / SATA AHCI

[image]

I tried with a 1 TB HDD (Western Digital WD BlueTM 2.5-inch HDD, wd10spzx-21z10t0). However, I don't see the common possibility to connect the HDD. On the picture you may see the HDD slot (currently with a black plastic part as a placeholder in it). But the only possible connector is on the side of that slot.

- Do I need another HDD type here?
- Maybe an adaptor can help here?
- Can I use SSD in this slot (I tried with SAMSUNG 850 EVO SSD, it works, for instance with HP Pro Book 440 G2)?

[image: HDD slot]

Comment: You probably need to order a part from Dell. If the laptop was built without a hard drive then they may have saved on cost by also not including the custom SATA ribbon cable that goes to that port on the motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Romen said in the comments, Dell probably saved cost to not include the adapter cable neccesary. But I can still answer the other things:

You can use all 2.5inch HDD types and SSD's. The Samsung EVO 850 will probably work, and if you need the extra storage and you have the budget, SSD's are really good for laptops.

Comment: Could you please give some recommendation also for the type of adapter which I could order?

Comment: Order one from dell.com

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, Dell send me these parts. Note, that asking in the shops did not yield much as they tell that Dell does not give any information. So you can buy at Dell only and some parts are really expensive (M2 screw about 12 EUR).

HDD case:
[image: HDD case]

---

Adapter:

[image]